# How to Output Fully window with all action in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, kivy

I am input some text and need output this text
for next work with him

Task: Output fully window for working with text &
make template of action for button/switch/other

.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager , Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class StartWindow(Screen):
    pass

class FindWindow(Screen):
    pass

class InputWindow(Screen):
    pass

class QuizWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SettingWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class GridLayout_(Widget):

    eng_word = ObjectProperty(None)
    ukr_word = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):
        print(self.eng_word.text, self.ukr_word.text)


kv = Builder.load_file('My.kv')
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

*after run code i am recive black window without no one widget
but i need workable window
and I do not understand how

**File My.Kv**
_it is description of two window , i am do not paste all because all code like 250 string  _

```
WindowManager:
    StartWindow:
    InputWindow:
<StartWindow>:
    name: "start"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            id: Welcome
            text: 'Welcome Vocabulary'
            font_size: 40

        GridLayout:
            spacing: 10
            padding: 50, 0, 50, 50
            cols: 2

            Button:
                id:Bttn_Input
                text: "  Input New Word"
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: (.33,.41,.45,1)
                font_size: 32
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "input"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                Image:
                    source: 'image\Add_pic.png'
                    size_hint: .2,.2
                    pos: root.width/25, root.height/3.2
               

            Button:
                id:Bttn_Find
                text: "Find"
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: (.70,.39,.92,.4)
                font_size: 32
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "find"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
                
                Image:
                    source: 'image\magnifier.png'
                    size_hint: .19,.19
                    pos: root.width/1.9, root.height/3.2
                

            Button:
                id:Bttn_Setting
                text: "Setting"
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: (.33,.41,.45,1)
                font_size: 32
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "setting"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
                Image:
                    source: 'image\Gear_pic.png'
                    size_hint: .2,.2
                    pos: root.width/17, root.height/10


            Button:
                id:Bttn_Quiz
                text: "Quiz"
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: (.38,.91,.44,.5)
                font_size: 32
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "quiz"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                Image:
                    source: 'image\Quiz_pic.png'
                    size_hint: .2,.2
                    pos: root.width/1.9, root.height/10


<InputWindow>:
    eng_word: eng_word
    ukr_word: ukr_word
    name: "input"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id:L_Inw
            text: "Input New Word"
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: 1, .4
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                id: Bttn_Inw
                text: " B \n a \n c \n k"
                size_hint: .2, 1
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "start"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                Label:
                    id:L1_Inw
                    text: "Eng word"
                TextInput:
                    id: eng_word
                    multiline: False
                Label:
                    id:L2_Inw
                    text: "Ukr word"
                TextInput:
                    id: ukr_word
                    multiline: False
                Button:
                    id:Bttn2_Inw
                    text: "Commit"
                    on_press:
                        root.btn()
```

Comment: Please include your `.kv` file.

Comment: @ApuCoder, excuse me . i have done it alredy

Comment: The program seemed to work pretty well on my end. Did you put the`.kv` file in the same directory as `.py` file ? Meanwhile I will suggest you to name your `.kv` file same as your App's subclass (minus 'App') but in lower case.

Comment: @ApuCoder, `main.py` file and `my.kv` file in one folder (all file named in lower case),
but it does not help
i need workable window with workable button
but recive black window

Comment: @ApuCoder,The program work pretty well on end. But button not work. It is main problem